# Print with other user on network printer (CUPS)

Tags: networking, printing

To start off in case that makes any difference: I am doing this **from a live-usb-stick** of 13.10 to check if everything works before actually installing Ubuntu and leaving Windows behind.

## Printing on a network printer

I print via network but the **print server only accepts certain usernames**. The 'ubuntu' username obviously isn't one of them.

As being forced to call the ubuntu user the same as the user allowed for printing is just a dirty workaround (which I didn't try but assume would work) I looked for a solution, but I didn't find any option to manually set a username in the GUI. So I googled.

## Changing the user

I found this [bug report #856776](https://bugs.launchpad.net/common-print-dialog-gtk/+bug/856776) via [Use different username on CUPS remote printing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61095/use-different-username-on-cups-remote-printing)

When printing with `lp -U username -d printername file.ext` everything works.

On the [last comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/common-print-dialog-gtk/+bug/856776/comments/14) of this issue I found what I believe to be a solution namely adding a directive in [client.conf](https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.7/ref-client-conf.html?VERSION=1.7&Q=) to force the username to something different.

But I couldn't make this work:

- `/etc/cups/client.conf` doesn't exist
- when I create `~/.cups/client.conf` and add `User bob` this doesn't help

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and maybe there is something I forgot. Restart something? Add something else? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I solved your problem, my answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61095/use-different-username-on-cups-remote-printing/497573#497573). Short version: set the "billing info" in the "print menu/jobs".

Comment: I'll try this and report back if it helps.